# How could i map json with jackson mapper?

Tags: java, jackson

How could i map json like this:

```
"Fields" : [
{"name" : "someName",
 "values" : [...]},
 {"name" : "someName1",
 "values" : [...]},
...
]
```

to structure similar to this: 
    List<Map<String, List<String>>>

For example with jackson mapper?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Technically, the above is not valid JSON. You would need to wrap the whole thing in { ... }. But that's semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jackson a data structure like this would map to json that you need.

```
public class Something {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Field> fields;
}

public class Field {
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    private List<?> values;
}
```

resulting in

```
{
    "fields" : [
        { "name" : "someName", "values" : [...] },
        { "name" : "someName1", "values" : [...] },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: So, my question is, how to  transform this  
"
    JsonProperty
    private String name;

   JsonProperty
    private List<?> values;  
 " 
to Map. When mapping json to object.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly. If you create an instance of `new Something()` and add a number of fields to it, Jackson will serialized it into the format you want - an array of json objects.